# Where to get 64bit php_zip.dll extension for php 7.0?

Tags: php, dll, configuration, php-7

I've converted my web site from php 5.4 to php 7.0, and now create zip functionality is not working properly. ZIP file is always corrupted after process.

LOG file shows following error warning :
PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library "C:\php\ext\php_zip.dll"

I think I need 64bit php_zip.dll extension as I'm using 64 bit php 7.0.
Can anyone redirect me to a link?

Problem : ZIP is not created.

Comment: BTW extension_loaded("zip") return true

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: @JCarlos Yeah I found the solution, visit this [link](https://pecl.php.net/package/zip) and use the latest extension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The PECL page for the PHP zip extension offers 32 and 64-bit PHP 7 Windows DLLs here:

https://pecl.php.net/package/zip/1.13.4/windows

Comment: tried after changing new dll but still not working... Zip file is still corrupted. But PHP7.x64_errors.log showed different warning this time: "PHP warning: module 'zip' already loaded in unknown on line 0"

Comment: @JustAProgrammer I have that error too, but I just comment line ;extension=php_zip.dll from php.ini, restart apache, then look into phpinfo() and zip was there. Finally run script and it works.
So don't add that line into your php.ini and just try it without it.